# Can't create infinite scroll with Firestore for vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The problem I'm having is that I've created a composable javascript page which gets the documents so that it can be used on several pages rather then typing it out everywhere I need to get a collection of documents I've been able to limit the amount of docs returned but I am unsure on how to call for more since I'm not getting the documents from the vue page which I need to get more.
Is there any way I can call a function based on the scroll event to get say another 8 docs when this occurs and if so how do I not just get the same 8 docs back again?
Heres what the javascript composable looks like I've limited the profiles returned to just 8.

```
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";
import { ref } from "vue"

const getPremium = () => {
    const Premium = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)

    const load = async () => {
        try{
            const res = await projectFirestore.collection('Premium').limit(8).get()

            Premium.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
               console.log(doc.data())
               return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
            })
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { Premium, error, load}
}

export default getPremium
```

This is what the script looks like to get the profiles on the vue page

```
<script setup>
import getPremium from "../Composables/getPremium.js";
const {Premium, error, load} = getPremium();
load();
</script>
```

Here is the vue Template

```
<div v-for =" Premiums in Premium" :key="Premiums.id" >
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'Samplepremium', params: { id: Premiums.id }}">

  <br>
     <p class="text-xl">{{ Premiums.name }}</p>
</router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

So what I was thinking was maybe I could call the load() function again whenever a scroll event occurred but how would I keep track of the last doc to return another 8 after it otherwise I'm just get the same 8 over and over again.
Sorry this was a little long but any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.